# How to check if a all the elements of a list is a particular element without using loop in TCL

Tags: list, search, tcl

I have a list { Desg Desg Desg Desg Desg Desg}

I want to see if there are any other elements in the list other than these . Also I dont want to run a loop .  Something like lcontain  ?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a loop?

Comment: That is my last option . just checking if there is something like lsearch which will do the trick ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `expr {[lsearch ... -not $list $pattern] >= 0}`

Comment: That's the only sane way to do it. (Of course, it just hoists the loop into the C implementation of `lsearch`, but that's the right place to do it…)

Comment: @sudeep Note that if you're the person building the list, there's probably a much faster way to do this, maybe with an array, a boolean variable or `if`/`switch` (you can still keep the list if you need it for something else). Like Donal said, `lsearch` has to go through all the elements (unless you `lsort` it first and use `lsearch -sorted`).

Comment: @potrzebie, unless `-all` is specified as well, `lsearch` won't go through *all* the elements as it stops at the first matching. But searching through the sorted list would definitely help as this turn the algorithm into binary search.